# HK is cyclic if H and K are both cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a finite group with normal subgroups $H$ and $K$ of relatively prime orders. Show that the group $HK$ is cyclic if $H$ and $K$ are both cyclic.

My attempt was to use the $2$nd Isomorphism Theorem, $H/(H \cap K)$ isomorphic to $HK/K$. Since $H$ and $K$ have relatively prime order, then $H \cap K={e}$, the trivial group. Therefore $H$ is isomorphic to $HK/K$. I am wondering how to apply normality to get $HK$ is cyclic if $H$ and $K$ are cyclic.

Comment: say $a$ generates $H$ and $b$ generates $K$ what can you say about the generator of $HK$ here you have to use the fact that they have relatively prime order

Comment: generator of HK is a multiple of a, and a multiple of b

Comment: exactly ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sunce $H$ and $K$ are normal in $G$, they are normal in $HK$, and since they intersect trivially, $HK\cong H\times K$, and by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, the direct product of cyclic groups of relatively prime orders is cyclic, so $HK$ is cyclic.

Comment: Can you please explain how to use chinese reminder theorem here? Thank you.

Comment: CRT says that, if $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, then given any integers $x, y$, there exists an integer $z$, which is unique mod $ab$, which is congruent to both $x \mod a$ and $y\mod b$. This gives a bijection between $C_{ab}\to C_a\times C_b$, and this bijection is in fact a group isomorphism since addition is preserved by taking mods.

Comment: Is it possible to show $HK$ is cyclic without the notion of direct product?

Comment: You could also argue that if $a$ generates $H$ and $b$ generates $K$, then $ab$ generates $HK$.